# retrieve data from .post

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter, .post

I'm using codeigniter, I had a problem to process a data using jQuery **`$.post`** function. I want to send a value such as **`subjectid`** to **ajax_get_subject_credit** function and retrieve another field within same database table. The result shows on another text field. Here is my code.

**View:**

```
$.post('<?php echo site_url('academic/ajax_get_subject_credit'); ?>', {'subjectid':subjectid}, function(data){

        $('#chours' + id).val(data); });
```

This get a value from drop-down and I want to make a text field automatic populate from drop-down. `#chours` is a text field ID.

**Controller:**

```
function ajax_get_subject_credit($result)
{
    $this->db->select('subjectid, subjectcredit');
    $query = $this->db->get('ref_subject');
    $result = $query->result_array();
    $query->free_result();
    $subjectid = array();
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        $result = $result + array($row['subjectid'] => $row['subjectcredit']);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

**Modified In Controller**

I also tried using this statement in controller for direct calling the field but still no success :

```
function ajax_get_subject_credit($subjectid)
{
    $this->db->select('subjectid, subjectcredit');
    $this->db->where('subjectid',$subjectid);
    $query = $this->db->get('ref_subject');
    $credithour = $query->row()->subjectcredit;
    $query->free_result();
    echo $credithour;
}
```

Comment: You say you want to use the `subjectid` POST value in your controller, but you aren't doing anything with it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am going to provide a general example here

in view file

```
$.post('<?php echo site_url("test/test"); ?>', {'id':1}, function(response){

   if(response.success)
   {
     alert(response.message);
   } else
   {
     alert('Something went wrong!!');
   }
}, 'json');
```

in controller Test.php

```
function test()
{
  $id = $this->input->post('id');

  //do additional stuff

  $result = 'i am coming right out of controller!! ';

  echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'message' => $result));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Dont use **return** to return value to AJAX. use `echo`

change this,

```
return $result;
```

to

```
echo $result;
```

Comment: change the returning variable name. you have already defined $result to get results from query. So it leads duplication

Comment: I think you are making array only. what is this array($row['subjectid'] => $row['subjectcredit']);?

Comment: I want to call `subjectcredit` value by submitting `subjectid` from main form and return the value of `subjectcredit` to `$result`.

Comment: why it should be array? you can pass a value know.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your method to return an array that the javascript can use to populate a dropdown, you probably don't want to return a string.

Try something like this:

```
function ajax_get_subject_credit()
{
    $query = $this->db->select('subjectid, subjectcredit')->get('ref_subject');

    $result = $query->result();

    $out = array();
    foreach($result as $row) {
        $out[$row->subjectid] = $row->subject_credit;
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($out);

}
```

This will return a JSON array to your view, which your javascript method can use to populate the dropdown with values and labels.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But in my case, I want to send a value using `subjectid` to function ajax_get_subject_credit and return the `credithour` within same table.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Result:

**In View :**

```
function subjectid_change(id, subjectid){
    //Set value
    setValue(id, subjectid);

    $.post('<?php echo site_url('academic/ajax_get_subject_credit'); ?>', {'subjectid':subjectid}, function(response){

        if(response.success)
        {
          $('#chours' + id).val(response.value);
        } else
        {
          alert('Something went wrong!!');
        }
    }, 'json'); }
```

**And my controller :**

```
function ajax_get_subject_credit()
{
    //Get Post Value
    $subjectid = $this->input->post('subjectid');
    //Select subjectid,subjectcredit FROM
    $this->db->select('subjectid, subjectcredit');
    //Where subjectid = 'subjectid'
    $this->db->where('subjectid',$subjectid);
    //Database name
    $query = $this->db->get('ref_subject');

    $credithour = $query->row()->subjectcredit;
    $query->free_result();
    $result = $credithour;

    echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'value' => $result));
}
```

Thanks to everybody who helped me.